# php date before 1970

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

im using PHP 5.3 and have read alot of material in that matter but still cant fins a solution.

I want to import birthdays 01/10/1945 from excel into mysql using php
whatever i tried did not give me the result (im getting a negative number)

here is the last solution that i have tried :

$data is the excel file (im using excel reader class for that)

```
$date_of_birth = ($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][11] - 25569) * 86400;
```

the result was -2207692800

what am i doing wring here ?

Comment: Where do you get this negative value? In PHP or in the MySQL table? Make sure the column type is DATE, as it can handle such dates.

Comment: excuse me, what is 25569?

Comment: There's absolutely no way to answer this question if you don't explain where `25569` comes from and what it is supposed to represent. To begin with, Excel has its own Epoch and PHP can handle dates as objects, so 1970 might not be relevant at all.

Comment: 25569 is the number of days between the Unix timestamp basedate and the MS Excel 1900 calendar basedate. OP's math is basically correct for converting an MS Excel timestamp (measured in days) to a Unix timestamp (measured in seconds)

Comment: Problem is that the value in $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][11] is not the MS Excel timestamp for 01/10/1945 (which should be 16711 for the 1900 calendar) .... by my calculation, it contains a value of 17, which would be 17th January 1900

Comment: This is very hard to understand for me, as the contents of `$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][11]` is 17. Are you sure you are accessing the right cell in the Excel sheet?

Answer (score 4):

Dates before the Unix epoch are represented as negatives in PHP, so you're not doing anything wrong.
When you use any of the `date time` functions on the timestamps, you'll get the correct value.

Comment: -2207692800 is not anywhere close to 01/10/1945, though. -788144400 is.

Comment: It is possible that PHP also represents microseconds or some such

Comment: You're right, to convert the date to a timestamp use the `mktime` function. Here's how I generated your timestamp. `var_dump(mktime(0,0,0,1,10,1945));` `Format: mktime(HH,MM,SS,Mon,Day,Year);`

Comment: Swap your method with the `mktime()` function. Good luck!

Comment: from a quick delve into the MySQL docs, and you may want to use the < from_unixtime > funciton, check the following page  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to convert a MSExcel date into an (incompatible) unix timestamp in order to put the data into MySQL? Just take the direct route:

```
$qry="INSERT INTO birthdays (person, birthday)
  VALUES ('$person', 18991231000000 + INTERVAL "
  . $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][11] . " DAY)";
```

(the integer value stored in MSExcel is the number of days since 31st Dec 1899)

Comment: Just watch out for 29th February 1900 :)

Comment: @MarkBaker 1900 is not a leap year - does Excel have a problem with that?

Comment: @ring0 - I know it isn't, but MS Excel believes it is, as did Lotus 1-2-3 before that (MS introduced that error into Excel to ensure compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3)